# Sony Air pods with really low volume Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

[image]

Sony Air pods with really low volume over Bluetooth in Ubuntu 20.04.

When I change the input to same as output, it works but with really bad quality and imbalance of sounds and delayed sounds.

Anyone came across this issue and found a solution?